# Linux C Ncurses issue

Tags: c, linux, null, ncurses

I'm having a strange problem with Ncurses in C that I can't seem to find documented anywhere, nor on the web. Maybe I'm not using the correct search terms?

### Here is the problem:

I have several windows and panels and LOTs of code. It all works perfectly UNTIL this happens:

`mvwprintw(windowptr[i], y, x, NULL); <-- That NULL value is what sets off the bomb`

I would expect that a NULL string would simply print a string of 0 length, but that's not what happens. What actually happens is that it corrupts all of my windows/panels. It seems to be somehow deleting all previously written chars and disabling the displaying of new chars on all windows / panels except the current window / panel. The current window / panel does not get blanked, but no new chars can be printed to it.

Is this a bug? ... or maybe an undocumented feature?

### Here's my Ncurses version:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i ncurse
ii  libncurses5:amd64                             6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1                           amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncurses5:i386                              6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1                           i386         shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncurses5-dev:amd64                         6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1                           amd64        developer's libraries for ncurses
ii  libncursesw5:amd64                            6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1                           amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
ii  libncursesw5:i386                             6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1                           i386         shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
ii  mtr-tiny                                      0.86-1ubuntu0.1                                 amd64        Full screen ncurses traceroute tool
ii  ncurses-base                                  6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1                           all          basic terminal type definitions
ii  ncurses-bin                                   6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1                           amd64        terminal-related programs and man pages
ii  ncurses-term                                  6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1                           all          additional terminal type definitions
```

Comment: Also see the [`mvwprintw(3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mvwprintw). You should probably use an empty format string in this case. Consider, you cannot `printf(NULL)`, so you should not `mvwprintw(..., NULL)`. `mvwprintw(..., "")` should side-step the landmine. (I can't find a Q&A about `printf(NULL)` to cite for you).

Comment: Is "" as a NULL terminated string != NULL?

said another way:
```"" == NULL```  <-- is this true?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that I using GNU C. I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: After some thought, I think I now understand.
"" is a pointer to an address who's value is NULL. NULL is a pointer to address 0x0. The two are not the same. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `"" == NULL` No. A `""` is a pointer that points to a readonly location with a single byte that contains zero. A `NULL` is a 0. They differ.

Comment: It's undefined behavior (for instance [this comment](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-44-passing-null-to-printf-in-c/)).  ncurses does a number of pointer checks, anyway, but could miss some useful ones.

Answer (score 0):

Actually (there's no sample [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to test in this question), ncurses does check for this null pointer and is expected to ignore the `printw` which would be called after the `wmove` part.

To see this, follow the source-code:

- [`mvprintw`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/d43e273aa3a4a69881cecdfd631d689fbd4224d8/ncurses/base/lib_printw.c#L110) is always a function call (due to the variable-length argument list)
- [`vw_printw`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/d43e273aa3a4a69881cecdfd631d689fbd4224d8/ncurses/base/lib_printw.c#L151) is the next step, which calls
- [`_nc_printf_string`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/d43e273aa3a4a69881cecdfd631d689fbd4224d8/ncurses/base/safe_sprintf.c#L221), which **[sees](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/d43e273aa3a4a69881cecdfd631d689fbd4224d8/ncurses/base/safe_sprintf.c#L227)** the null-pointer for the format, and returns null,
- making `vw_printw` **[ignore](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/d43e273aa3a4a69881cecdfd631d689fbd4224d8/ncurses/base/lib_printw.c#L162)** the call.